# Mario less, struggling with nested for loop logic

Tags: c, cs50

Hello I have got my code to work but don't understand the logic, I found a flow chart for how nested for-loops work, and with that, I was able to mix things around until I got it to output correctly but while trying to read it I still haven't had that "ah-ha" moment I guess while looking at it. first time coding and first time with an online course so I feel like I've buried myself under my own questions and felt like I haven't been asking myself the right ones when trying to learn. still looking for that moment if someone could answer in question form but will most likely have to follow up questions if it doesn't click after some time. if someone would be open to that thank you and if not but you still want to post an answer I understand anything helps. thanks

```
int s;
int h;
for (int r = 0; r < n ; r++)
{ 
   for( s = r + 1; s < n; s++)
   {
       printf(" ");
   }
   for( h = 0; h <= r; h++)
   {
       printf("#");
   }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: 'I have got my code to work but don't understand logic'.....how?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments :

```
int s;
int h;
for (int r = 0; r < n ; r++). // loop on n rows
{ 
   for( s = r + 1; s < n; s++) // start the row with n-(r+1) space characters
   {
   printf(" ");
   }
   for( h = 0; h <= r; h++) // continue with r+1 # char
   {
       printf("#");
   }
printf("\n"); // next line
}
```

This show kind of reverse Pyramid
If you want to understand what you are doing, just add comments to your code (before to know what you will code and after if you found specific solutions for some coding problems)